# How would this PHP array look in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I got a little lazy and just used PHP to store all these values, I should be using Javascript to do this though. Whats the best way to do the following in Javascript? I would then be using jQuery's .each function to loop through it.

```
  $accessories = array (
       array('name' => 'Chrome pull out wire Basket 500 & 600 wide ', 'price' => '60'),
       array('name' => 'Chrome shoe rack 2 Tier', 'price' => '95'),
       array('name' => 'Chrome Shoe Rack 3 Tier', 'price' => '145'),
       array('name' => 'Chrome pull out trouser rack', 'price' => '40'),
       array('name' => 'Pull out tie rack', 'price' => '135'),
       array('name' => 'Pull Down hanging Rail 450mm to 1190mm width', 'price' => '33.50'),
       array('name' => 'Corner Hanging Rail', 'price' => '33.50')
        );
```

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, so you'd have to build it as a series of objects in an array.

```
var accessories = [
    { 'name' : 'Chrome pull out...', 'price' : 60 },
    { 'name' : 'Chrome shoe rack..', 'price' : 95 }
];
```

You could then cycle over it using `$.each` as you requested:

```
$.each( accessories, function(){
    alert( this.name );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/HXwMc/

#### Quickly Convert PHP Array to JSON

You can get the above structure easily by passing the array through [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode( $accessories );
```

Comment: +1, and you (possibly without knowing) corrected the spelling of accessories which the OP should probably do as well.

Answer (score 4):

It would probably look like this:

```
var array = [
    {"name": "Chrome pull out wire Basket 500 & 600 wide ", "price": "60"},
    {"name": "Chrome shoe rack 2 Tier", "price": "95"},
    {"name": "Chrome Shoe Rack 3 Tier", "price": "145"},
    {"name": "Chrome pull out trouser rack", "price": "40"},
    {"name": "Pull out tie rack", "price": "135"},
    {"name": "Pull Down hanging Rail 450mm to 1190mm width", "price": "33.50"},
    {"name": "Corner Hanging Rail", "price": "33.50"}
];
```

Note that this is an **array of objects**. JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, those are objects.

Answer (score 3):

As Jonathan noted, that's an array of objects in Javascript. It would look like this

```
var accessories = [
  { 
    name: 'hello',
    price: 1.00,
  },
  {
    name: 'world',
    price: 2.50,
  }
]
```